# NetBeans 7 - How to remove Marked Occurrences when caret is moved away from variable?

Tags: netbeans

In NetBeans 6.9, when you move the caret away from a variable its marked occurrences stop being marked. In NetBeans 7, they just remain marked. This is very annoying. How can I fix it?

I tried looking in the settings and there's nothing to fix this. I don't want to disable this cause I need it and I'll happily live with a solution where I'll have to use a keyboard shortcut to highlight occurrences.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Great news! NetBeans 7.2 is out and it has the option properly implemented for PHP (In all previous 7.x versions it was only implemented for Java).

Go to "Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Highlighting" and uncheck the "Keep Marks" option.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a known bug: http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=187627

No way around it, I'm afraid.

EDIT: of course, you can always get auto-(de)marked behavior by ticking check-box in Tools->Options->Editor->Mark Occurrences->Keep Marks

Comment: Ouch. Let's hope this gets fixed soon with a keyboard shortcut to enable/disable or preferably with an option to keep/not-keep it highlighted. Cheers.

Comment: "Keep Marks", I'm using the latest version of NetBeans for PHP (7.0.1) and I don't have this option. Which NetBeans version are you using? Any plugins installed? Thanks.

Comment: Try enabling installed plugins under Options->Plugins->Installed. My guess is that "Java SE" is the one you want.

Comment: I've installed JavaSE and now I can see the option for Java but not for PHP. I wonder why as it used to work perfectly before for PHP! Let's hope it gets implemented soon for PHP. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

In Netbeans 8.1 I've found that feature in the window below:
[image: Option to change marked occcurences]

If you **uncheck all checkboxes**, editor will never highlight occurences. On the other hand you can prefer to check first checkbox in order to highlight occurences but when focus gone highlighting will disappear. (keep marks is unchecked)